# How does the NSAutoreleasePool autorelease pool work?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsautoreleasepool, foundationkit

As I understand it, anything created with an **alloc**, **new**, or **copy** needs to be manually released. For example:

```
int main(void) {
    NSString *string;
    string = [[NSString alloc] init];
    /* use the string */
    [string release];
}
```

My question, though, is wouldn't this be just as valid?:

```
int main(void) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool;
    pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *string;
    string = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
    /* use the string */
    [pool drain];
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, your second code snippit is perfectly valid.

Every time -autorelease is sent to an object, it is added to the inner-most autorelease pool. When the pool is drained, it simply sends -release to all the objects in the pool.

Autorelease pools are simply a convenience that allows you to defer sending -release until "later". That "later" can happen in several places, but the most common in Cocoa GUI apps is at the end of the current run loop cycle.

Comment: where's the end of the current run loop cycle, if I don't have an loop?

Comment: Shouldn't "outer-most" be "inner-most"?

Comment: `an object` should be `an object that is a subclass of NSObject or NSProxy and doesn't override -autorelease`.

Comment: EDIT: Changed outer-most to inner-most.

Comment: Important : If you use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), you cannot use autorelease pools directly. Instead, you use @autoreleasepool blocks. From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Thanks The run loop is not a loop. It's not a language construct like `for` or `while`. It's rather a dispatch mechanism that manages the different execution states and events within a thread.

Answer (score 37):

### NSAutoreleasePool: drain vs. release

Since the function of `drain` and `release` seem to be causing confusion, it may be worth clarifying here (although this is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAutoreleasePool/drain)...).

Strictly speaking, from the big picture perspective `drain` is *not* equivalent to `release`:

In a reference-counted environment, `drain` does perform the same operations as `release`, so the two are in that sense equivalent. To emphasise, this means you do *not* leak a pool if you use `drain` rather than `release`.

In a garbage-collected environment, `release` is a no-op.  Thus it has no effect.  `drain`, on the other hand, contains a hint to the collector that it should "collect if needed".  Thus in a garbage-collected environment, using `drain` helps the system balance collection sweeps.

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to 'leak' a `NSAutoreleasePool`.  This is because pools operate like a stack.  Instantiating a pool pushes that pool on to the top of that threads autorelease pool stack.  `-release` causes that pool to pop from the stack **AND** any pools that were pushed on top of it, but for whatever reason were not popped.

Comment: In what way is this relevant to what I wrote?

Comment: I like how he took the time to bold AND. *SNAP!*

Answer (score 17):

As already pointed out, your second code snippet is correct.

I would like to suggest a more succinct way of using the autorelease pool that works on all environments (ref counting, GC, ARC) and also avoids the drain/release confusion:

```
int main(void) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSString *string;
    string = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
    /* use the string */
  }
}
```

In the example above please note the **@autoreleasepool** block. This is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Please note, that autorelease is not permitted with ARC.

Comment: To clarify, one has to use the `@autoreleasepool` block with ARC.

Answer (score 7):

No, you're wrong. The documentation states clearly that under non-GC, -drain is equivalent to -release, meaning the NSAutoreleasePool will **not** be leaked.

Comment: I wondered why Xcode would generate code with -drain if that were the case. I used -drain because I thought it was equivalent to -release based on the code generated by Xcode.

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to 'leak' a `NSAutoreleasePool`: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-997594

Answer (score 0):

What I read from Apple:
"At the end of the autorelease pool block, objects that received an autorelease message within the block are sent a release message—an object receives a release message for each time it was sent an autorelease message within the block."

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Answer (score 0):

sending autorelease instead of release to an object extends the lifetime of that object at least until the pool itself is drained (it may be longer if the object is subsequently retained). An object can be put into the same pool several times, in which case it receives a release message for each time it was put into the pool.

Answer (score -2):

Yes and no. You would end up releasing the string memory but "leaking" the NSAutoreleasePool object into memory by using drain instead of release if you ran this under a garbage collected (not memory managed) environment. This "leak" simply makes the instance of NSAutoreleasePool "unreachable" like any other object with no strong pointers under GC, and the object would be cleaned up the next time GC runs, which could very well be directly after the call to `-drain`:

> drain
>
> In a garbage collected environment, triggers garbage collection if memory allocated since last collection is greater than the current threshold; otherwise behaves as release.
>   ...
>   In a garbage-collected environment, this method ultimately calls `objc_collect_if_needed`.

Otherwise, it's similar to how `-release` behaves under non-GC, yes. As others have stated, `-release` is a no-op under GC, so the only way to make sure the pool functions properly under GC is through `-drain`, and `-drain` under non-GC works exactly like `-release` under non-GC, and arguably communicates its functionality more clearly as well.

I should point out that your statement "anything called with new, alloc or init" should not include "init" (but should include "copy"), because "init" doesn't allocate memory, it only sets up the object (constructor fashion). If you received an alloc'd object and your function only called init as such, you would not release it:

```
- (void)func:(NSObject*)allocd_but_not_init
{
    [allocd_but_not_init init];
}
```

That does not consume any more memory than it you already started with (assuming init doesn't instantiate objects, but you're not responsible for those anyway).

Comment: I don't feel comfortable leaving this answer as accepted when your information about drain isn't quite right. See
http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000051-SW5
Update and I will re-accept.

Comment: What is inaccurate about the reply? In a garbage collected environment (as stated), drain does not delete the AutoReleasePool, so you *will* leak memory unless you used release. The quote I listed was straight from the horse's mouth, the docs on drain.

Comment: Loren: Under GC, -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] will trigger a collection. -retain, -release, and -autorelease are all ignored by the collector; that's why -drain is used on autorelease pools under GC.

Comment: In the documentation for 'drain':
In a managed memory environment, this behaves the same as calling release.
Thus you will *not* leak memory if you use 'drain' instead of release.

Comment: `-[NSAutoreleasePool release]` in a garbage-collected environment is a no-op. `-[NSAutoreleasePool drain]` works in both reference-counted and garbage-collected environments.