# Why does 'self' protect memory space?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, memory-management

In a navigation based app, I initialize an array in my app delegate without using self. When accessed in the RootViewController's cellForRowAtIndexPath:, all array objects are there and I can see it is an NSCFArray.  Once the app loads, I click a table cell and in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, that same array has a type of NSArray, no objects and I get a EXC_ BAD_ACCESS error.  If I precede the array with self in the app delegate, all is fine.  Why is that?

Below is the app delegate .h file:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

  UIWindow *window;
  UINavigationController *navigationController;
  NSMutableDictionary *aDict;
  NSArray *aArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *aArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *aDict
@end
```

The array and dictionary are synthesized in the .m file.  I initialize the array in the app delegate .m file like this:

```
aArray = [self.aDict allKeys];
```

It is accessed like this in both root controller methods:

```
theDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
[theDelegate.aArray objectAtIndex:2];
```

Only when I reach didSelectRowAtIndexPath: does it fail.  Doing this in the app delegate makes everything work:

```
self.aArray = [self.aDict allKeys];
```

I didn't do anything to myArray between cellForRowAtIndexPath: and didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. Why does it fail in the first scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `self.aArray` makes use of the synthesized property. You defined the property as `(nonatomic, retain)`, this means that whatever it is set to, that value will be retained. What was happening when you *didn't* use this was that the `allKeys` was being auto-released, and by the time you actually used it, it was gone. Using the property retained that value, making it live past its scope.

Hope that made sense, sorry if I misunderstood you.

Further reading:

- [Apple Docs - Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)
- [Apple Docs - Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)
- [Apple Docs - NSAutoreleasePool](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [Question Regarding How NSAutoreleasePool Works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427/how-does-the-nsautoreleasepool-autorelease-pool-work)

I'm sure there are more reader friendly articles out there, but now you know what to look up: Objective-C memory management, and Objective-C properties. It's pretty important so I recommend you do this.

Comment: Thanks. Why was the autorelease occurring "only" at the time between the two root controller methods and not before cellForRowAtIndexPath: for example? cellForRowAtIndexPath: had already accessed aArray two times (2 rows). Is it random? One more thing: What is it (myArray) called when you don't use 'self'? Using 'self' accesses the property but not using it means...

Comment: Not using self is just setting it directly. You really have to read up on how properties work. Properties are just auto-generated methods that set the variable but in the way you define (retain, copy, etc.). You could have the same behavior if you just wrote your own setter/getter methods, but properties do this automatically and also let you use the self.something syntax. properties basically just save you some grunt work, time, and redundancy.

Comment: And yes, autoreleased objects can be considered to release randomly. Actually, they are usually released when the pool they are in gets released, I suggest you read up on autoreleased objects as well. The pool is NSAutoreleasePool, I'll include a link in my post. So it's not completely random per se, but you shouldn't make any assumptions and just retain/copy in such situations.

Comment: So 4thSpace, did I answer your question? If so, I'd appreciate it if you accepted the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to force this behavior?  I've setup a simple app that uses the above scenario without the dictionary.  So there is only an array on the app delegate.  I can't get it to fail.  I'm not using self in the app delegate when accessing the instance variable.

Comment: What are you using instead of the dictionary keys to set the value of the array?