# Even with self, object still autoreleased

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, memory-management

In regards to this posting [Why does 'self' protect memory space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481871/why-does-self-protect-memory-space/1481882#1481882), I'm using 'self' to access aArray.  Yet, I still get an invalid object in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method.

In the root controller, I access aArray like this:

```
MyAppDelegate *theDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];  
NSString *aKey = [theDelegate.aArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Would that have something to do with aArray loosing its reference?  Why wouldn't it occur in cellForRowAtIndexPath: (the first use of it outside of MyAppDelegate proper)?

Answer (score 2):

This question doesn't make sense.  Or, rather, the answer is still "go read and understand the documentation linked to in the answer to your other question".

Specifically:

- [Apple Docs - Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)
- [Apple Docs - Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1)
- [Apple Docs - NSAutoreleasePool](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [Question Regarding How NSAutoreleasePool Works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427/how-does-the-nsautoreleasepool-autorelease-pool-work)

There is no magic about memory management.  There is nothing special about self vs. any other kind of object reference.   The dot notation is merely short hand for a method call;  nothing special to it, either.

Until you understand these things, you'll be chasing ghosts and not actually solving the real problems in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If `aArray` is a property that is set to retain, then you may be over-releasing it somewhere.  It doesn't seem entirely clear in your question, but if it's the object at index 0 that's invalid, it may be it that was over-released.  If you're using Xcode 3.2 on Snow Leopard you may want to make sure you're using the Clang static analyzer.  It can help find such over-releases.

Comment: Yes - I'm running Clang. Object at index zero is valid.

Comment: Was using 'assign' rather than 'retain'.  Didn't catch it for a while.  Problem solved.

Comment: So I guess instead of over-releasing, it was under-retained.