# GNUStep NSAutoreleasePool incompatibility

Tags: objective-c, gnustep, nsautoreleasepool

According to [another Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427/how-does-the-nsautoreleasepool-autorelease-pool-work) the `drain` message is an Apple-only call:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSLog (@"Hello");
[pool drain];
return 0;
```

Is it safe to replace `drain` with `release`? I am trying to port an Objective-C application to run on Linux (Ubuntu at the moment). Should I give up even before I have started? (I'm already having issues trying to get `NSURLConnection` working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Apple's documentation of `drain`:

> [...] this method behaves the same as release. [...]

So draining an autorelease pool means deallocating it inevitably. In my opinion, Apple should deprecate `drain` since it only creates confusion.

But:

> **Special Considerations:**
>   In a garbage-collected environment, `release`
>   is a no-op, so unless you do not want
>   to give the collector a hint it is
>   important to use `drain` in any code
>   that may be compiled for a
>   garbage-collected environment.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It didnt occur to me to read the Apple docs to understand non apple libraries (:

Comment: -drain will not be -- will never be -- deprecated exactly because it supports the garbage collector.  This is a critical boon to performance in code that must run both GC and non-GC, such as certain plug-ins and the system frameworks.