# Big time Leaking in Objective-C Category

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, categories, nsautoreleasepool

I created a custom NSString Category which lets me find all strings between two other strings. I'm now running into the problem of finding that there are a lot of kBs leaking from my script. Please see code below:

```
    #import "MyStringBetween.h"

@implementation NSString (MyStringBetween)

-(NSArray *)mystringBetween:(NSString *)aString and:(NSString *)bString;
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *autoreleasepool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSArray *firstlist = [self componentsSeparatedByString:bString];
    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for (int y = 0; y < firstlist.count - 1 ; y++) {
        NSString *firstObject = [firstlist objectAtIndex:y];
        NSMutableArray *secondlist = [firstObject componentsSeparatedByString:aString];
        if(secondlist.count > 1){

            [finalArray addObject:[secondlist objectAtIndex:secondlist.count - 1]];
        }
    }

    [autoreleasepool release];

    return finalArray;
}
@end
```

I admit that I'm not super good at releasing objects, but I had believed that the NSAutoreleasePool handled things for me.

The line that is leaking:

```
NSMutableArray *secondlist = [firstObject componentsSeparatedByString:aString];
```

Manually releasing secondlist raises an exception.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427/how-does-the-nsautoreleasepool-autorelease-pool-work

Comment: Btw, your function returns an array instead of a string.

Comment: Also, unless you're calling this method on a thread without an autorelease pool encapsulating it, you shouldn't need to make a new autorelease pool just for this method.  If you're calling it on the main thread, you've likely got one set up for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is the line that is leaking:

```
NSMutableArray *secondlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And it isn't that big of a leak (just an empty mutable array).  Still, don't do that.

In particular, the line:

```
    secondlist = [[firstlist objectAtIndex:y] componentsSeparatedByString:aString];
```

Is assigning over the reference to the empty mutable array.

Also `FinalArray` should be named `finalArray`.

Comment: Please view my new code. The same secondlist line is being marked by instruments as leaking. By "big leak", in my own project, it is causing a 40kB leak.

Comment: It's not a just an empty array — objects are added later. It will also leak all those objects since the array retains them. And `finalArray` needs to be autoreleased too.

Comment: @Chuck Stylistically, finalArray should absolutely be autoreleased.  However, the author could be releasing it outside the method (although they may not be.)

Answer (score 1):

finalArray is leaking.  You should autorelease it before returning it but make sure you do it either before allocating the autorelease pool or after releasing it.