# Auto releasing memory allocations

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

In my code I am auto releasing certain references. Most of the time I have seen that auto release is run under NSThreadPool. So is it required to run this under NSThreadPool? If so what will be the difference between pool release and pool drain.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required to run inside NSThreadPool. There is a similar post about pool release and pool drain. 
[How does the NSAutoreleasePool autorelease pool work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427/how-does-the-nsautoreleasepool-autorelease-pool-work/181043#181043)