# How to avoid leaking in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, crash, nsautoreleasepool

i am getting thing crash log:

```
2011-07-21 23:18:51.233 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fbdef0 of class NSURL autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.233 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1462e38 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.233 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1462e38 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.233 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fb32b0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.235 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fc04e0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.235 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5f98960 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.235 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fa9c70 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.550 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fbfbb0 of class NSHTTPURLResponse autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.550 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fb5840 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.550 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fb1400 of class __NSArrayM autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.551 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5f83e70 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.551 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fbd480 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.551 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fb31b0 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.551 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fa9aa0 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.551 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fa6110 of class __NSArrayI autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-21 23:18:51.552 iFeel[87679:910b] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x5fb9700 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

Can any body help me to avoid crashing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likely that you are seeing this because you are executing code on a thread without an autorelease pool.  The autorelease pool is heavily used by all of Apple's APIs, so it is important to wrap one around your entire thread.  An example of this would be as follows:

```
- (void)myThreadMethod:(id)anObject {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"This is some objective-c code...");
    [pool drain];
}
```

The [pool drain] part is very important.  Without that snippet of code, all of the objects that were autoreleased during your threads lifetime will be leaked.

Comment: I am using xcode 4.2 with ARC. In that NSAutoreleasePool is deprecated. My app is not crashing but in log same log is coming. Is it harmful to my app? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an instance of `NSAutoreleasePool`. Check out the [NSAutoreleasePool Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details and examples.

You may also want to skim through the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i) to see why it's important to set this up and what `autorelease` actually does.

I also found the discussions on this post helpful: [How does the NSAutoreleasePool autorelease pool work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427/how-does-the-nsautoreleasepool-autorelease-pool-work)

Answer (score 1):

From Apple documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

The NSAutoreleasePool class is used to support Cocoa’s
 reference-counted memory management system. An autorelease pool stores
 objects that are sent a release message when the pool itself is
 drained.

Important: If you use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), you cannot
 use autorelease pools directly. Instead, you use @autoreleasepool
 blocks. For example, in place of:

```
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
// Code benefitting from a local autorelease pool. 
[pool release];
```

you would write:

```
 @autoreleasepool {
     // Code benefitting from a local autorelease pool. 
}
```

@autoreleasepool blocks are more efficient than using an instance of
 NSAutoreleasePool directly; you can also use them even if you do not
 use ARC.