# High virtual memory usage + low allocations on iOS

Tags: ios, memory

I have code that has a low amount of active allocations (about 5 MB according to Instruments), but a high amount of system memory usage (over 100 MB). I know the code is leak-free, and I'm not seeing any allocation spikes after some optimization, but I'm still crashing due to the high amount of memory usage.

I Googled around a lot and see that I'm supposed to be using the VM Tracker instrument, which confirms my high memory usage, but I'm not sure how to address this situation. I'm using as little memory as possible, it's still too much on an iPad 1, and I don't have the knowledge or tools to figure out how to get the OS to not mark so much memory as dirty when I'm not actually using it. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Profile tool and select memory +allocations. Click the VM tracker and take a snapshots. This results in a list with resident dirty and virtual memory usage per object type. This will give you an indication where to look.

I think the most common problem is that you have a lot of autoreleased objects that reside in the autoreleasepool. The following link explains more on how to handle autoreleasepools: 
[How does the NSAutoreleasePool autorelease pool work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427/how-does-the-nsautoreleasepool-autorelease-pool-work)